# php/show videos for mobile device and online convert format

Tags: php, video

I am developing an upload system...

what is the best method to shows most videos and audio format specially for smartphone device?

Is there any open source php scripts class do do this? I wana something like youtube.

Or a way to convert videos format...

Comment: PHP will have nothing to do with Video Formats, HTML5 is what need to learn -- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp  -- and you can use Javascript Pluggings also to play videos --- http://www.videojs.com/

Comment: If you're providing the videos, you have to transcode them into files that browsers/clients can use (and each one may support a different set of them). Honestly, if you can, offload this to Youtube or a white-label video host like Brightcove.

Comment: Ok i think i may read you question wrong, well you can use a premade PHP Class like this one --- http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3747-PHP-Manipulate-and-convert-videos-with-ffmpeg-program.html -- to convert most video formats using ffmpeg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon has a service for transcoding video. https://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/?nc1=h_l2_as and the [AWS SDK has a PHP client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/service-elastictranscoder.html) for it.

Other option is (assuming you are using a Linux server) is to use [ffmpeg and the PHP classes for it](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) to do the transcoding. Of course, you'll want to use some sort of worker/message queue to perform the actual transcoding into the final format(s) you need for smartphones. Oh, and ensure that all the right codecs are installed for ffmpeg to work.

Comment: Thank you...FInaly I installed ffmpeg...becuase I think amazoon is too expensive for a free upload hosting :)